# SQLite Database insertion not working from AsyncTask

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, android-sqlite, android-database

I have done some background activities inside an asynctask class on my Application. And the result from this is saving into SQLite DB. But db insertion is not happening and never showing any error on console. Please see below code and let me know if you see any issues.

```
  private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        String username;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
   
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TestScreen.this,R.style.MyTheme);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Large);
           
            progressDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            ArrayList<String> array_time = dbManager.fetchTimeStamp();
            username = strings[0];
            PyObject pyObject1 = null;
          
            if (! Python.isStarted()) {
                Log.d("Py..","Py..");

                Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(getApplicationContext()));


                Python py = Python.getInstance();
                PyObject pyObject =py.getModule("app");
            
                pyObject1 = pyObject.callAttr("score",mStartTestTime,endTestTime);

               
                count =  pyObject1.asList().get(0).toInt();
                p_total_time = pyObject1.asList().get(1).toDouble();
              
                p_score= pyObject1.asList().get(6).toDouble();

            }

            return username;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

          
            dbManager.insertStatistics(s,helper.TABLE_STATISTICS,,p_count,
                    p_total_time,Category,p_score);
            }
    }
```